# Submitting comment on iOS sends me to limbo

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app

When I successfully submit a comment (on an answer at least), I am taken to a blank page, and when I press the Back button I am returned to the app home screen instead of the question I was actually just viewing & commenting on.

My place on the page is (of course) competently lost and I have to manually find the question again and scroll to find where I left off.

If it is relevant: I was browsing questions from the Feed / HNQ screen.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,5)
- OS Version: Version 12.0 (Build 16A366)

Comment: I noticed this issue as well, and was planning on asking about it eventually. I think it happens by all comments. But I think it only started happening recently.

Comment: @alex please consider upvoting that duplicated issue for visibility. Bugs are easily ignored if they get buried in meta.

Comment: @Glorfindel confirmed duplicate, thanks!